# Is protest considered as Unsportsmanlike Conduct in tennis?

Tags: rules, tennis

ITF Senior Regulation define Unsportsmanlike Conduct as:

> Any misconduct by a player that is clearly abusive or detrimental to the Sport, but does not fall within the prohibition of any specific on‐site offence contained herein. In addition, unsportsmanlike conduct shall include, but not be limited to, the giving, making, issuing, authorizing or endorsing any public statement having, or designed to have, an effect prejudicial or detrimental to the best interests of the tournament and/or the officiating thereof.

Does this definition also include protest in a game and if not which law will handle protest?